# Python will not write to a CSV file and there are no errors; the print function works

Tags: python, csv

I have 3 lists of integers. They are then converted into strings. When trying to write them to the CSV file, the file itself is generated, but completely empty. This has stumped all Python users in my lab.

I have tried isolating the different lists and writing them to CSVs. They all return blank.

The print function works.

```
LP = [25,26,27,28,30,67,71,9,17,18,3,4,46,47,48,49, 55, 56, 65, 66] #(190)

RP = [92,93,98,107,114,115,116,156,117,160,119,144,145,135,136,137,138,155,106,
      154] #(190)
RF = [90,94,95,96,97,101,102,103,104,105,106,113,118,120,121,129,128,134,141,
      142,143,157,158,151,152,153,159,136,137,138,155,92,93,107] #(561)

LP = list(map(str, LP))
RP = list(map(str, RP))
RF = list(map(str, RF))

f = open("All Connections Between Nodes.csv", "w")


def run(lobe):
    seperator = ","
    for num in lobe:
        for num2 in lobe:
            if lobe.index(num2) <= lobe.index(num):
                pass
            elif lobe.index(num) == lobe.index(num2):
                pass

            elif lobe == LP:
                f.write("" + (num) + seperator + (num2) + "")
                f.write("\n")
                print(num, num2)
            elif lobe == RP:
                f.write("" + (num) + seperator + (num2) + "")
                f.write("\n")
                print("" + (num) + seperator + (num2) + "")
            elif lobe == RF:
                f.write("" + (num) + seperator + (num2) + "")
                f.write("\n")
                print("" + (num) + seperator + (num2) + "")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    run(LP)
    run(RP)
    run(RF)
```

The CSV file should look like this:

```
25 26
25 27
25 28
```

And so on. Each pair should only exist once. (e.g., if 25-26 exists, there should not be a 26-25)

Comment: You didn't close the file, so the data may still be in a buffer rather than actually written to disk until you actually exit the Python interpreter.  Programming languages tend to work this way because it's vastly more efficient than writing each little bit of data directly to disk as it's generated.

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: Your example runs correctly on my machine with python 3.7. A file is written and it does contain data. What version of python are you running and on what OS? Is there anything noteworthy about your system or configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `f.flush()` as in:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(LP)
    run(RP)
    run(RF)
    f.flush()
```

or, set the file to be unbuffered when you create the object:

```
f = open("All Connections Between Nodes.csv", "w", 0)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, the f.flush() fixed the script! Do you mind explaining why? Or what I did wrong?

Also how do I give you credit? I just made my account today haha

Comment: You are probably running from some sort of GUI and the file was not closed.

Comment: In this case, `flush()` forces buffered data to be written to disk. It is possible that the write was not complete (are your data larger than what you've shown in your example?) when you were checking the file, or that the file was open when the write occurred and thus was not "refreshing" when you checked it.

Comment: @xibalba1 yes, I actually have a total of 8 lists. I have only displayed 3 of them. That makes sense, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the scope is not correct with open the file:

```
LP = [25,26,27,28,30,67,71,9,17,18,3,4,46,47,48,49, 55, 56, 65, 66] #(190)

RP = [92,93,98,107,114,115,116,156,117,160,119,144,145,135,136,137,138,155,106,
      154] #(190)
RF = [90,94,95,96,97,101,102,103,104,105,106,113,118,120,121,129,128,134,141,
      142,143,157,158,151,152,153,159,136,137,138,155,92,93,107] #(561)

LP = list(map(str, LP))
RP = list(map(str, RP))
RF = list(map(str, RF))

seperator = ','

def run(lobe):
    with open("All Connections Between Nodes.csv", 'w') as f:
        for num in lobe:
            for num2 in lobe:
                if lobe.index(num2) <= lobe.index(num):
                    pass
                elif lobe.index(num) == lobe.index(num2):
                    pass

                elif lobe == LP:
                    f.write(''+(num)+seperator+(num2)+'')
                    f.write('\n')
                    print(num,num2)
                elif lobe == RP:
                    f.write(''+(num)+seperator+(num2)+'')
                    f.write('\n')
                    print(''+(num)+seperator+(num2)+'')
                elif lobe == RF:
                    f.write(''+(num)+seperator+(num2)+'')
                    f.write('\n')
                    print(''+(num)+seperator+(num2)+'')   




if __name__ == '__main__':


    run(LP)
    run(RP)
    run(RF)
```